# Git subfolder has ".io" and cannot be opened

Tags: git, github, io

I started a new git project. Please see link https://github.com/alfance/alfance.elric
But the folder that contains all the web app components (www) has an "io" extension. it cannot be opened or edited. I wonder what is wrong with my git set up since it never happened before. I tried to find similar problems but failed to do so. 
I also attached an image just in case [image] 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a symbolic link or a submodule.

Since there is no `.gitmodules` file in this repo, it might be a symbolic link.
The icon looks like the submodule icon and not the symbolic link icon.

Someone has committed it to your git, of course you will not be able to open it unless you have the submodule remote url.

Comment: I am confused, I was the only one committing and that was right after the first commit.

Comment: Looks like you added a symbolic link on your repository, Check your local repository to see this locally.

Comment: You have committed it by mistake i assume. Since there is no content git treat this link as folder and will check it out as folder with no content.

Comment: Well? what did you found?

Comment: I remember started the subfolder accidentally with ".io" . right now i am just creating a brand new repository to see if that works

Comment: Yes it was my mistake. it all works now. Thanks a lot!